# checking if a date falls in given date range using mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have these two columns in my database table 'mycodes'

```
code_valid_from_date
code_expiry_date
```

I need to check if a given date falls in valid period of the dates given in mycodes tables.

For example,

```
mycodes
id, code_valid_from_date, code_expiry_date, name
1, 2013-08-01, 2013-08-28, 'Code 1'
2, 2013-08-29, 2013-09-20, 'Code 2'
3, 2013-07-01, 2013-07-28, 'Code 3'
```

I tried this query,

```
SELECT
DATEDIFF(NOW(), code_valid_from_date) valid_from_days, 
DATEDIFF(code_expiry_date, NOW()) expiry_days_left
FROM mycodes
```

then in my php code I check both of these DATEDIFF are positive numbers then its a valid code. What if I have to compute this validity in the mysql query itself rather than checking using PHP? How do I do that?

PS: I could also use a BETWEEN in WHERE clause but that will return rows which fall in that given range but I need to list all the records with status of expired or not expired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mysql knows to compare dates, so you can use something like:

```
SELECT (NOW() >= code_valid_from_date AND NOW() <= code_expiry_date) AS valid FROM mycodes
```

Comment: Hmm - let me try that

Answer (score 0):

SELECT (NOW() BETWEEN code_valid_from_date AND code_expiry_date) AS valid FROM mycodes

Answer (score 0):

This is my code to find if a date range falls within another date range.
  I'm sure you could modify my choosing the same date as your arrival and departure date.

Example that works for me and my queries:

```
SET @PerBeg = ’2010-01-01’;
  SET @PerEnd = ’2010-01-31’;

  SELECT  
      Reservation.ArrivalDate AS ArrivalDate, 
      Reservation.DepartureDate AS DepartureDate, 
  . . . 

  WHERE

  fBoolActyInPeriod(ArrivalDate,DepartureDate,@PerBeg,@PerEnd)
```

using these functions

```
  FUNCTION fBoolActyInPeriod contains this code
  RETURN IF (fBoolFirstDateEarlier(ActyEnd, PerBeg) OR fBoolFirstDateEarlier(PerEnd, ActyBeg),0, 1)

  FUNCTION fBoolFirstDateEarlier contains this code
  RETURN IF (DATEDIFF(first, second) < 0, 1, 0)
```